# Why my account has been flagged?

Tags: github

> Your account has been flagged.
> Because of that, your profile is hidden from the public. If you believe this is a mistake, contact support to have your account status reviewed.

Help me.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't look like a practical, detail question about using a web application. I'm not including more details as this question looks to be closed after the moderation strike and eventually might be automatically deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You should contact github support. You can submit a request to gain access back to your account: https://support.github.com/request